# App Installed Event Receiver -> Access Denied

Tags: provider-hosted-app, office-365, remote-event-receiver

I am using `AppInstalled` event receiver to create a list in host web and then breaking its role inheritance. The list is created successfully but I am getting `"Access Denied"` while breaking role inheritance. The host web is `MySite`. The code is as follows:

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateAppEventClientContext(properties, useAppWeb: false))
            {
                if (clientContext != null)
                {
                    Web hostWeb = clientContext.Web;
                    clientContext.Load(hostWeb);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    var listCollection = hostWeb.Lists;
                    _spService.CreateListInHostWeb(Constants.LIBRARY_NAME, Constants.TEMPLATEID_DOCUMENTLIBRARY, listCollection);
                    clientContext.Load(listCollection);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    //code to break role inheritance
                    List library = hostWeb.Lists.GetByTitle(Constants.LIBRARY_NAME);
                    submissionLibrary.BreakRoleInheritance(false, false);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); //error here
                }
            }
```

I have assigned the following permission

```
<AppPermissionRequests>
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="Manage" />
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web/list" Right="FullControl" >
  <Property Name="BaseTemplateId" Value="101" />
</AppPermissionRequest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but from what i see, i guess you should not use

```
_spService.CreateListInHostWe
```

but add library to

```
listCollection
```

using

```
ListCreationInformation
```